# DataProc BigQuery Connector Access Across Projects

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am writing a Spark Job to run on a DataProc cluster in Project A but the job itself will pull data from a BigQuery instance in Project B using the BigQuery Connector. I have owner privileges for both project, but the job is run using a service account. The response I'm getting in the stack trace is this:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Access Denied: Table ABC:DEF.ghi: The user me-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table ABC:DEF.ghi.",
    "reason" : "accessDenied"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Denied: Table ABC:DEF.ghi: The user me-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table ABC:DEF.ghi."
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, Dataproc clusters run on behalf of service accounts instead of individual users; this is intentional, since different users may be creating Dataproc clusters in a shared project where they do not want their personal permissions to leak across other members of the org using the same project, and instead should define permissions according to service accounts which each represent a particular scope of workloads.

In this case, all you have to do is go into project B and add the service account from project A as one of the roles that can access BQ in project B. If it's not a complex arrangement withlots of users and different teams, you could just add it as "project viewer" on project B, otherwise you'll want something more fine-grained like a "bigquery viewer" or "bigquery editor".

Add that service account the same way you would add any user to project B.

Comment: Giving the service account the right access has fixed that problem but now the spark job just seems to hang

Comment: If you're using the BigQuery connector in unsharded export mode, then the job has to wait for BigQuery to export the data to GCS before starting to process it. Sharded export mode should allow processing to start sooner, but may be less efficient. If you will be reading the data repeatedly without it changing, you could also just export from BQ into GCS manually first and then use standard file input formats to read directly from those GCS files in your spark job.

Comment: hm ok, is sharded export mode something I can just turn on? If so how?

Comment: It's controlled with `mapred.bq.input.sharded.export.enable`: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/BigQueryConfiguration.java#L82

Comment: However, the default is actually "true" already, so it's unclear whether your job is indeed hanging because of waiting for a BigQuery export. I suppose it's at least worth a try to flip it on and off; you can set it in your code when creating the BigQuery input, or you can set it as a [mapred property](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties#how_the_properties_option_works) when creating your cluster, or you can manually set it in /etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml

Comment: if the value is true by default that's good enough for me, do you think it'd be quicker to use tmp of DataProc cluster's HDFS rather than gs?.. is that even an option?